# JavaScript dymanically change CSS background style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to dynamically change my background image by continuously looping through an array of image paths. The code works if I log the output to a console, but I cannot get the image to actually change.

**Original CSS:** (I am overriding the default style from another CSS file)

```
<style>
      .jumbotron { 
         background: #7da7d8 url('images/rotunda2.jpg') no-repeat center center !important; 
      }
</style>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var count = -1;
var images=new Array("images/image1.jpg","images/image2.jpg","images/image3.jpg");
setInterval(swap, 5000);

function swap(){
    $('.jumbotron').css("background", "#7da7d8 url('"+images[++count % images.length]+"') no-repeat center center !important");
    console.log(images[++count % images.length]);
}

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: first guess is whether or not the relative path to the image resolves correctly.

Comment: have demo ? or link ?
anyways shouldn't you checking condition for if(count > images.length) {count==-1;}or clearInterval if not loop ?

Comment: I don't see anything resetting back your count, seems like it deeps incrementing forever. Also, why do you have to use 2 different class names? myelement and jumbotron?

Comment: My mistake, myelement should be jumbotron. Also, i do want it to loop forever.

Comment: Is your JavaScript waiting for the document to load?

Comment: See the edit above. I have $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: @littleK, i understand you want it to loop forever, but u need to reset your counter when it reaches the length of your images array, coz if it kept increasing, let's say to count = 3, your images doesn't have an index 3 there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think change css is a good idea, you may define some classes, and dynamically change the classes on the element!

html:

```
<div class="dynamicBg class1"></div>
<div class="dynamicBg class1"></div>
```

css:

```
.dynamicBg {
    background-color: #7da7d8;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
.class1 {
    background-image: url('images/image1.jpg');
}
.class2 {
    background-image: url('images/rotunda2.jpg');
}
.class3 {
    background-image: url('images/rotunda3.jpg');
}
.class4 {
    background-image: url('images/rotunda4.jpg');
}
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    var classStr = 'class1 class2 class3 class4',
        classArr = classStr.split(' '), i = 0,
        $dynamicBg = $('.dynamicBg');
    setInterval(function() {
        i = i > 3 ? 0 : i + 1;
        $dynamicBg.removeClass(classStr).addClass(classArr[i]);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're swap function seems kind of odd.  Typically for something like this, you could have a counter that gets incremented and then just resets to 0 and starts over.  Also make sure you are running in an onload event handler context.

```
var count = 0;
var images=new Array("images/image1.jpg","images/image2.jpg","images/image3.jpg");

function swap(){
    //get the next image
    var nextImage = images[count];
    console.log(nextImage);

    $('.jumbotron').css("background-image", nextImage);

    //increment count
    count = count > images.length - 1 ? 0 : count+=1;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(swap, 5000);
});
```

aside from that, make sure to check your error console for errors, and for 404's indicating you might have bad image paths

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).load(function() {
    var count = -1;
    var images = ['images/image1.jpg', 'images/image2.jpg', 'images/image3.jpg'];
    setInterval(swap, 5000);

    function swap() {
        var img = images[++count % images.length];

        $('.jumbotron').css('background', '#7da7d8 url(' + img + ') no-repeat center center !important');
        console.log(img);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the document to load:

```
$(document).load(function()
{
    var count = -1;
    var images=new Array("images/image1.jpg","images/image2.jpg","images/image3.jpg");
    setInterval(swap, 5000);

    function swap(){
        $('.jumbotron').css("background", "#7da7d8 url("+images[++count % images.length]+") no-repeat center center !important");
        console.log(images[++count % images.length]);
    }
});
```